# Socket Programming -- Sending and receiving images

Tags: python, c++, sockets, opencv

I hope that I am in the right place.
I apologize if I am not in the right section for my question.

I am trying to send images from client written in python to server written in c++.
When I execute both of them, the server side seems connected but client side gave me this error (IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level)

I am going to post the server side:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define SERVER_PORT htons(50007)

int main() {

    char buffer[1024];
    int n;

    int serverSock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = SERVER_PORT;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /* bind (this socket, local address, address length)
       bind server socket (serverSock) to server address (serverAddr).  
       Necessary so that server can use a specific port */ 
    bind(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));


    // wait for a client
    /* listen (this socket, request queue length) */
    listen(serverSock,1);

    sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t sin_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    int clientSock=accept(serverSock,(struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &sin_size);

    while (1 == 1) {
            bzero(buffer, 1024);

        //char *buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (240*360));    
        FILE *output;    
        output = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");    
        unsigned int readBytes = 0;    
        while(true)    
        {    
            int ret = recv(clientSock, buffer+readBytes, (240*360)-readBytes, 0);    
            if (ret <= 0)    
            {    
                break;    
            }    
                readBytes += ret;    
        }    
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), readBytes, output);    
        fclose( output );    

        //Mat img_2 = imread( "test.jpg");

            //receive a message from a client
            n = read(clientSock, buffer, 500);
            cout << "Confirmation code  " << n << endl;
            cout << "Server received:  " << buffer << endl;

            strcpy(buffer, "test");
            n = write(clientSock, buffer, strlen(buffer));
            cout << "Confirmation code  " << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
    close(serverSock);
}
```

This is client Side:

I wish somebody help me out.

```
import socket
import sys,os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 50007

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))


fpath ='/Users/salemalqahtani/Desktop/NetworkingPart/sss.png'
pic = open(fpath, 'rb')
chunk = pic.read(1024)
client_socket.send(str.encode("STORE " + filePath))
t = time()
while chunk:
    print("Sending Picture")
   client_socket.send(chunk)
   chunk = pic.read(1024)
pic.close()
print("Done sending")
print("Elapsed time = " + str(time() - t) + 's')
client_socket.close()
return "Done sending"
```

Edit:
The image is sending from client side to server side and server will reply a message received....

Comment: Well, it clearly says that the problem is in your indentation. You should check in your python code that every function, loop, condition, etc is correctly indented. Also, I see a `return` statement but no function defined, either it's a wrong statement or you didn't provide all the relevant code

Comment: It seems like line 2 and 3 of your `while chunk:`-body are not properly indented and are likely to cause that error.

Comment: How is the server supposed to figure out what the last character of the `filePath` is? It seems you just run a string of unknown length into the beginning of the image data with no way for the server to tell where one ends and the other begins. If you're not experienced with TCP, you should always start by either using an existing protocol (like FTP) or writing out a specification for the protocol you're going to use. Otherwise, it's impossible to tell whether the client is broken or the server is broken since there are no rules.

Comment: You're passing a maximum read size of 86400 to `recv`, but your buffer is only 1024. You're also attempting to sendi a PNG but saving with a "jpg" suffix.

Comment: If you are stuck with something like this, you should be making sure to study and fully understand the fundamentals of Python **first**, before attempting to do something complex like interfacing Python code to a server across a low-level socket, or using OpenCV to analyze images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be a simple indentation error? It looks like there is any extra space before print

```
while chunk:
   print("Sending Picture")
   client_socket.send(chunk)
   chunk = pic.read(1024)
```

Comment: You guys right. I fixed the problem but now when I run the server and client there is no thing happened and it shows me on client side           client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Comment: Guys, Now it is working but I got an empty image file on the server and this command ERROR reading from socket: Undefined error: 0. Also, in the client side I got,     client_socket.send(chunk)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe